# can't cut slash at the end of url in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, wagtail

I have Django app, There I use some lib. All urls in this lib are ends with slash( / )

```
path(f"sprite-{get_sprite_hash()}/", home.sprite, name="wagtailadmin_sprite"),

path('login/', account.LoginView.as_view(), name='wagtailadmin_login'),
```

I need to make that When I will go on this urls without slash in the end this urls steel working. APPEND_SLASH is not working here, becouse it's only redirect url -> url/ and I need working url without slash and redirections

Answer (score 0):

keep `APPEND_SLASH = False` and remove `/` from your url path regexes

```
path(f"sprite-{get_sprite_hash()}", home.sprite, name="wagtailadmin_sprite"),
path('login', account.LoginView.as_view(), name='wagtailadmin_login'),
```

Comment: I whrite before that it's urls from some lib. I cannot change lib urls

Comment: You right, you cannot just change 3rd party django app urls as you wish. You can add url prefix to those urls when including them in your `urls.py` file. You would have to redefine those urls completely in your own `urls.py`  to be able to change them the way you want.

Comment: You right, you cannot just change 3rd party django app urls as you wish. You can add url prefix to those urls when including them in your `urls.py` file. You would have to redefine those urls completely in your own `urls.py`  to be able to change them the way you want.

Comment: you mean, create own path and use 3rd party views for them?